# ¿Cómo puedo imprimir los datos en un TreeMap?

Tags: java

Tengo un método que se llama **verFamilia** el cual va a imprimir los datos que están contenidos en el **TreeMap**, también intente imprimirlo con dos **for** y no pude.

Tengo este **TreeMap** creado

```
TreeMap<Persona, ArrayList<Persona>> familia = new TreeMap<Persona, ArrayList<Persona>>();
```

este es el método donde quiero implementar

```
    static void verFamilia(TreeMap<Persona, ArrayList<Persona>> familia) {
    
            for (Entry<Persona, ArrayList<Persona>> map : familia.entrySet()) {
         
        Persona persona = map.getKey();
        ArrayList<Persona> array = map.getValue();
        for (int i =1; i <=array.size(); i++) {
            System.out.println("La familia tiene un hijo llamado  "
                    + persona.getNombre()  + "su padre se llaman  " + array.get(i-1).getNombre() + "  y su madre se llama  " + array.get(i).nombre );
        }
        System.out.println("");
    }

    
}
```

y me genera un error

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: com.CamiloOlmos.ws.rest.service.Persona cannot be cast to java.lang.Comparable
at java.util.TreeMap.compare(TreeMap.java:1294)
at java.util.TreeMap.put(TreeMap.java:538)
at com.CamiloOlmos.ws.rest.service.Main.main(Main.java:42)
```

ese error hace referencia a la linea 42 de mi código, la cual es esta

```
TreeMap<Persona, ArrayList<Persona>> familia = new TreeMap<Persona, ArrayList<Persona>>();
    familia.put(hijo, padres);

    verFamilia(familia);
```

Answer (score 1):

El error es sumamente claro: tu clase `Persona` no es una instancia de `java.lang.Comparable`.

La claves utilizadas con la clase `TreeMap` deben ser `Comparable`s si no se ha especificado un `java.util.Comparator` al momento de construir la instancia del `TreeMap`. Esto es así porque esta estructura de datos utiliza un árbol [Rojo-Negro](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C3%81rbol_rojo-negro) para almacenar la información de manera ordenada de acuerdo a las claves, para lo cual hace uso del método `Comparable.compareTo()` sobre las claves asociadas a los valores almacenados.

Tienes dos soluciones posibles:

**1 - Usar un `Comparator` al crear el `TreeMap`**

```
TreeMap<Persona, ArrayList<Persona>> familia = new TreeMap<Persona, ArrayList<Persona>>(new PersonComparator());
```

**2 - Hacer que `Persona` implemente `Comparable`**

```
public class Persona implements Comparable<Persona> {
    
    // Resto del código de la clase

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Persona o) {
        // Lógica de comparación de personas
        return comparingResult;
    }
}
```